# How do I retrieve the template from an IPFIX file using libfixbuf?

Tags: templates, netflow

I am trying to use the CERT tools to read and parse an IPFIX file. The docs say to grab the "internal" template from the file, though every call relating to templates seems to require a template id (tid) or other information that I don't have. It's a total chicken-and-egg problem and I can't seem to figure it out. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

To identify templates from data records you need to look for the Set ID.  The Set ID will tell you if the record you are looking at is a template or data set. Anything greater than 255 is a data set.  The Set Id for a template is in IPFIX is 2. (0 to NetFlow v9, the 2 formats are deceptively similar).  See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5101#section-3.3.2  Once you find Set Id 2 the very next field should be TemplateId for the template.

This wiki page shows an example of the IPFIX packet.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_Flow_Information_Export